# Cloud Run Qs :: max-instances + concurrency + threads (gunicorn thread)

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, gunicorn, google-cloud-run

(I'm learning Cloud Run acknowledge this is not development or code related, but hoping some GCP engineer can clarify this)

I have a PY application running - gunicorn + Flask... just PoC for now, that's why minimal configurations.

`cloud run deploy` has following flags:

```
--max-instances 1
--concurrency 5
--memory 128Mi
--platform managed
```

`guniccorn_cfg.py` files has following configurations:

```
workers=1
worker_class="gthread"
threads=3
```

I'd like to know:

1) `max-instances` :: if I were to adjust this, does that mean a new physical server machine is provisioned whenever needed ? Or, does the service achieve that by pulling a container image and simply starting a new container instance (`docker run ...`) on same physical server machine, effectively sharing the same physical machine as other container instances?

2) `concurrency` :: does one running container instance receive multiple concurrent requests (5 concurrent requests processed by 3 running container instances for ex.)? or does each concurrent request triggers starting new container instance (`docker run ...`)

3) lastly, can I effectively reach `concurrency` > 5 by adjusting gunicorn `thread` settings ? for ex. 5x3=15 in this case.. for ex. 15 concurrent requests being served by 3 running container instances for ex.? if that's true any pros/cons adjusting `thread` vs adjusting cloud run `concurrency`?

additional info:
-  It's an IO intensive application (not the CPU intensive). Simply grabbing the HTTP request and publishing to pubsub/sub

thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, it's not appropriate on Stackoverflow to ask "cocktail questions" where you ask 5 things at a time. Please limit to 1 question at a time in the future.

1. You're not supposed to worry about where containers run (physical machines, VMs, ...). `--max-instances` limit the "number of container instances" that you allow your app to scale. This is to prevent ending up with a huge bill if someone was maliciously sending too many requests to your app.
2. This is documented at https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-concurrency. If you specify `--concurrency=10`, your container can be routed to have at most 10 in-flight requests at a time. So make sure your app can handle 10 requests at a time.
3. Yes, read Gunicorn documentation. Test if your setting "locally" lets gunicorn handle 5 requests at the same time... Cloud Run’s `--concurrency` setting is to ensure you don't get more than 5 requests to 1 container instance at any moment.

I also recommend you to read the officail docs more thoroughly before asking, and perhaps also the [cloud-run-faq](https://github.com/ahmetb/cloud-run-faq) once which pretty much answers all these.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions. I had looked at those links but could not get satisfactory answers (sorry I should have mentioned that earlier). actually few of your comments clarified now to me a) the diff. between `--max-instances` and `--concurrency`.. and b) how `--concurrency` is related to Gunicorn `thread` param. thx for answering.

Answer (score 0):

There's a great blog describing gunicorn performance tuning with regards to concurrency & parallelism (processes, threads and “pseudo-threads”) and with regards to the application consumption profile -

> If the bottleneck is memory, start introducing threads. If the
> bottleneck is I/O, consider a different python programming paradigm.
> If the bottleneck is CPU, consider using more cores and adjusting the
> workers value.

https://medium.com/building-the-system/gunicorn-3-means-of-concurrency-efbb547674b7